# PHP multidimensional arrays populated from MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, multidimensional-array, html-table

I am creating a holiday reporting tool to help me keep track of my remote workers, also using this an excuse as I am learning to code as a hobby.

I need to create a summary of everyone's holiday in a table (individual dates across the top, names down the side) but am stuck and need some help.

I have two tables, one with the user details and another storing the holiday records tied together using a userid. I only record the start and end date of the period and am struggling to understand how I can get the required information into a multidimensional array to build the HTML table from.

I'm sure it's using a for each loop but can't get my head around it, can any one help?

Comment: Plz, provide the structure of tables: user details and holiday records. And split your question into smaller ones: cause people don't want to spend too much time, writing the whole application for you.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL :

If your dates are timestamp or datetime, you can use something like :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(birthdays.your_date_field, 6, 5) AS bday, GROUP_CONCAT(users.nickname)
FROM birthdays
JOIN users USING (user_id)
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(birthdays.your_date_field, 6, 5)
ORDER BY bday ASC
```

You'll get a row per distinct dates and all your users having their birthday separated by a comma ( `,` ).

Some notes about this request :

- `SUBSTRING(birthdays.your_date_field, 6, 5)` : if your `your_date_field` is a datetime or a timestamp, it will contains a date with `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` format, so we need to cut this string to get `MM-DD` format.
- `GROUP_CONCAT(users.nickname)` indicates that if several rows enters the same group, columns will be concatained using a comma (`,`), instead of only using the first one that enters the group.
- `GROUP BY` will use a column to group your results, so that all users who have their birthday the same day will be grouped together. This is also useful if you want to make calculations (such as COUNT, SUM, ...) for distinct values of a column in a single request.

Example :

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id int,
  nickname varchar(32)
);

insert into users ( id , nickname )
values ( 1, 'mike' ), ( 2, 'jack' ), ( 3, 'santa' ), (4, 'mario');

CREATE TABLE birthdays (
  id int,
  birthday datetime
);

insert into birthdays ( id , birthday )
values ( 1, '1982-01-01' ), ( 2, '1983-03-11' ), ( 3, '1984-01-01' ), ( 4, '2011-06-04' );
```

Result :

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING(birthdays.birthday, 6, 5) AS bday, GROUP_CONCAT(users.nickname)
    -> FROM birthdays
    -> JOIN users USING (id)
    -> GROUP BY SUBSTRING(birthdays.birthday, 6, 5)
    -> ORDER BY bday ASC;
+-------+------------------------------+
| bday  | GROUP_CONCAT(users.nickname) |
+-------+------------------------------+
| 01-01 | mike,santa                   |
| 03-11 | jack                         |
| 06-04 | mario                        |
+-------+------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Demo : [click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a637/1)

---

PHP :

A PHP implementation to get those results could be :

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_base", 'username', 'password');

$request = <<< EOT
  SELECT SUBSTRING(birthdays.birthday, 6, 5) AS bday, GROUP_CONCAT(users.nickname) AS nickname
  FROM birthdays
  JOIN users USING (id)
  GROUP BY SUBSTRING(birthdays.birthday, 6, 5)
  ORDER BY bday ASC;
EOT;

$rows = $dbh->query($request)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($rows);
```

Will give you :

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["bday"]=>
    string(5) "01-01"
    ["nickname"]=>
    string(10) "mike,santa"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["bday"]=>
    string(5) "03-11"
    ["nickname"]=>
    string(4) "jack"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["bday"]=>
    string(5) "06-04"
    ["nickname"]=>
    string(5) "mario"
  }
}
```

Now, if you want array of arrays instead of comma-separated values, you can [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) them (if nicknames doesn't contain commas of course).

Something like :

```
$days = array();
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
  $days[$row['bday']] = explode(",", $row['nickname']);
}
var_dump($days);
```

Gives you :

```
array(3) {
  ["01-01"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "mike"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "santa"
  }
  ["03-11"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "jack"
  }
  ["06-04"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "mario"
  }
}
```

I think you get everything, good luck for your implementation.